# Determinant of Matrix using Recursion in C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++

Using C++ to calculate Determinant of Matrix:

```
int pw(int a){
    if(a%2==0)return 1;else return -1;
}
float det(vector<vector<float> > &arr, int rows){   
    vector<vector<float> > arr2;
    float dett=0,hk;
    if(rows==2){        
       dett= (arr[0][0]*arr[1][1]-arr[0][1]*arr[1][0]);
    } else {        
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){            
           hk=arr[0][i];arr2=arr;
           arr2.erase(arr2.begin());
           for(int k=0;k<rows-1;k++)arr2[k].erase(arr2[k].begin()+i);
           dett=dett+pw(i)*hk*det(arr2,rows-1);
         }  
    }
    return dett;
}
```

The same function in C# has an issue: when the loop reaches i=1, `arr` isn't the same between the c++ and c#.

```
    int pw(int a)
    {
        if (a % 2 == 0) return 1; else return -1;
    }
    double det(List<List<double>> arr)
    {

        int rows = arr.Count;
        List<List<double>> arr2;
        double dett = 0, hk;
        if (rows == 2)
        {
            dett = (arr.First().First() * arr.Last().Last() - arr.First().Last() * arr.Last().First());
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
            {
                hk = arr[0][i]; arr2 = arr;
                arr2.RemoveAt(0);
                foreach (List<double> k in arr2) k.RemoveAt(i);
                dett = dett + pw(i) * hk * det(arr2);
            }
        }
        return dett;
    }
```

Comment: "don't work" is not a useful description of a problem

Comment: Why are you using `First` and `Last`.  Just do `arr[0][0]`.  Also `Last` is not necessarily the second item which is what you're looking for in the C++ code.

Comment: @juharr the statement is guarded by a count check.

Comment: @UmairM A count check of the length of`arr` but not the length of the inner list.  But the big problem is that it kills readability.

Comment: No. It's not wrong in First or Last. I checked. It's wrong when Recursion start. You know. Arr suppose not change but it's change when Recursion start.

Comment: " So C# sucks? Or I've something wrong in my code?" given that you said " but in C# it don't work." leaves only one conclusion....

Comment: @Minh I didn't say that was the problem. It's just unnecessary.

Comment: "Arr suppose not change but it's change when Recursion start." if you do this `arr2 = arr` and make changes to `arr2` it will change `arr` because you don't copy the matrix but only assign the reference to it. both elements still point to the same object! Also if recursion starts then you have a different object with one row less that you have passed into the recursive call, why do you wonder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And I check when the loop reach i=1, "arr" isn't the same when Recursion start.

Yes, that is because you are using `arr2 = arr`, which doesn't copy the List, `arr2` is still the Reference to `arr` . What you can do is `arr2 = new List<List<double>>(arr);` to make a new List with the Elements of `arr`.

**EDIT** 
To Copy the List inside of the List, you can do this.
`arr2 = new List<List<double>>(arr.Select(x => new List<double>(x)));`

Comment: It's keeping delete arr when use new like you said. It's impossible. ><

Comment: @minh What do you mean?

Comment: You also have to Copy the `k` inside the `foreach`. Short way to Copy the inside of the List is to do this. `arr2 = new List<List<double>>(arr.Select(x => new List<double>(x)));`

Comment: Okayyy. It works. Thank you very very much. But honestly, now I start hating C#.. ><

Answer (score 1):

The `arr2 = arr;` statement does different things in the two languages.

In C++, it makes a copy of the data, so that changes to `arr2` will not change `arr`.

In C#, this assignment will update what `arr2` refers to, without making a copy.  So changes to `arr2` will also change `arr`.  You'll need to explicitly make a copy of `arr`.

Comment: It seem right. But how exactly I make a copy when I can't use "=" in c#?